# Django OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'static'

Tags: python, django, apache, permissions, django-staticfiles

I tried almost for a week, but could not solve this problem, and could not find anything online, that can help me.
I have a multi-domain server with Centos 5.3, and a Django project, I must deploy. I installed python 2.7 to /usr/local/python2.7 for Django 1.3 to work, also installed and enabled mod_wsgi.
Next, what I did, was checkout this project, and create virtualenv in home directory of user, who will own this application. I created wsgi script:

```
import os
import sys
import site

# path to domain specific virtual environment where python packages will be installed
site.addsitedir('/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

sys.path.append('/home/user/domain.com/project/')
sys.path.append('/home/user/domain.com/project/application/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

application = WSGIHandler()
```

and configured virtualhost.

```
<VirtualHost \
79.98.31.117:80\
            >
    ServerName masinis.lt
    ServerAlias \
            www.masinis.lt

    DocumentRoot "/home/user/domain.com/"

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/domain.com/project/wsgi_script.wsgi

    <Directory "/home/tomas/masinis.lt/liveopenly/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>


    Alias /static/ /home/user/domain.com/project/application/static/

    <Directory "/home/user/domain.com/project/application/static/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What I call project, is actually a folder for virtualenv, instructions and application itself.Application in this case is django project - it has apps, settings and other stuff inside. Also it uses external applications, that are stored in virtualenv folder.

When I try to get to domain.com, I get 500 error. And error_log gives me this:

```
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43] mod_wsgi (pid=11655): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/user/domain.com/project/masinis_lt.wsgi'.
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 273, in __call__
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     return callback(request, **param_dict)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/application/middleware.py", line 44, in server_error
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     return HttpResponseServerError(t.render(Context({'MEDIA_URL': settings.MEDIA_URL})))
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 123, in render
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     return self._render(context)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     return self.nodelist.render(context)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     return node.render(context)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 127, in render
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     return compiled_parent._render(context)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     return self.nodelist.render(context)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     return node.render(context)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 127, in render
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     return compiled_parent._render(context)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     return self.nodelist.render(context)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     return node.render(context)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_static/templatetags/django_static.py", line 208, in render
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     symlink_if_possible=self.symlink_if_possible)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_static/templatetags/django_static.py", line 493, in _static_file
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     _mkdir(os.path.dirname(new_filepath))
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_static/templatetags/django_static.py", line 624, in _mkdir
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     _mkdir(head)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_static/templatetags/django_static.py", line 624, in _mkdir
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     _mkdir(head)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]   File "/home/user/domain.com/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_static/templatetags/django_static.py", line 626, in _mkdir
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43]     os.mkdir(newdir)
[Mon Feb 27 00:40:10 2012] [error] [client 78.63.254.43] OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'static'
```

When I try to run in development mode (manage.py runserver), everything running, but it looks, like static file are not found, when accessing the page. While server log shows 302 response...
What could be the problem?

Comment: What are the permissions of -> /home/user/domain.com/project/application/static/

Comment: In cases like this, it is good to know what exactly is going wrong. Since you're on linux you could use the strace command to trace the server process. It will tell you exactly what directory it tries to create and why it fails. `man strace` will get you started.

Comment: Looks like user www (the one running the web server) doesn't have access to `/home/user/domain.com/...`. You can try changing ownership of those directories to group "www". There is however a bigger issue here - with multiple domains you shouldn't use this simple setup unless you trust all the users. Mod_wsgi isn't of great help here, because it would require Apache to run as root for it to be able to select the identity of a user...

Comment: Apache does start as root and has the required permissions to change user. For the case of the Django application, you do this by using mod_wsgi daemon mode and configure the daemon mode process group to run as the required user. Remembering of course to tell mod_wsgi to then run the Django application in that daemon process group.

Comment: I found a main problem. The path for DJANGO_STATIC_SAVE_PREFIX (I don't actually know for which app it is used) was indicated relative, not absolute, and it appeared, that server tried to create directory 'static' in root of the server.
But another problem appeared: the files in static folder are all in place, but when I load a page, it looks like they are not found...